# Where should the Graph API be used for an iOS App, client side or on Server side using Web Api

Tags: swift, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api

We are using Graph API for the first time and have few questions on where to call it from.

The iOS app we are building has a lookup screen, where a user can type in a few characters on the search input box and search for people registered on the Azure AD tenant.

I have a couple of options to implement this, as below:

Option 1: iOS app directly calls the graph API (GetUser) and displays results as it is returned.

Option 2: Delegate the request to server-side API, which calls the graph API and returns the data to the iOS app to render.

In Option 1, the iOS does not need to do an extra API call. However, it should manage token acquisition  for the Graph API call. The iOS app, additionally calls protected web apis,  which need separate tokens.

In Option 2: iOS has one source to call, it acquires token and calls the protected web API, which at the backend handles the Graph API call.

A future requirement is to expand graph API usage so that we can get data from other services ex: mail, file etc.  if the graph API scope increases, the iOS app will need to manage the tokens for each resource separately. Hence, I am thinking of going with option 2, where the server API handles all the call logic.

Any thoughts on this are most welcome.

Thanks for reading through the question.

Comment: Option 1 would be better for you because AAD will handled the authentication and your iOS app can just call graph api limited to the permissions that the user has granted. It will also be easy to add new resources as only one API is integrated, no proxies. If you have to use option 2, the problem will be how to secure the serveside API and still authenticate users. You will be doing auth twice. Between iOS and Server then between Server and Graph. Unless you want to share token from iOS to Server which is also not a good idea. Let me know then I can post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response DanStan. Sorry, it took longer to get back.
For now, we went with option1.   However, we can see that we may need additional data resources that need to be fetched with graph API, ex: MS Teams, Mail (Exchange).  If we need to get separate tokens for each these resources, it may be better to compose it from the server side? so option 2 may be good for this use case?